# How is FirebaseAnalytics web for flutter used?

Tags: flutter, firebase-analytics

There is no documentation currently how to use the FirebaseAnalyticsWeb flutter plugin.

So here is my working example. It's more straightforward than I initially thought, but nevertheless, I posted here. Hope this can benefit others.

Answer (score 0):

Add both firebase_analytics_web package to your project pubspec.yaml
Run flutterfire configure
That makes a firebase_options.dart config file

Init your code (decide for yourself if you want to use the global variabele, for my project, I did ;))

```
late FirebaseAnalyticsWeb analytics;

void main() async {

  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

  analytics = FirebaseAnalyticsWeb();
  analytics.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
  analytics.logEvent(name: "testevent");

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```